# Applescript Progress Bar Freezes at end and stays active while next routine is called

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

I am making an Applescript that automates my local development workflow. Whats happening is I'm using an Applescript progress bar to run while I check for script dependencies (i.e. MAMP). The progress bar appears, animates perfectly, and is returning my routines that check for dependencies as expected. The problem is, even when the progress bar reaches its total steps count, the progress bar freezes, even when the script calls a dialog box in the following routine, and the script freezes.

Here is the routine that starts the progress bar:

```
on dependency_check()
    set progress description to "Access Granted: "
    set progress additional description to "Preparing..."

delay 0.5

set progress total steps to 100
repeat with i from 0 to 100
    try
        if i = 0 then
            set progress additional description to "Checking Dependencies..."
            delay 0.5
        else if (i > 0 and i < 10) then
            set progress additional description to "Checking Node.js..."
        else if i = 10 then
            set progress additional description to node_exists()
        else if (i > 10 and i ≤ 20) then
            set progress additional description to "Node.js is installed..."
        else if (i > 20 and i < 30) then
            set progress additional description to "Checking mamp-cli..."
        else if i = 30 then
            set progress additional description to mampcli_exists()
        else if (i > 30 and i ≤ 40) then
            set progress additional description to "mamp-cli is installed..."
        else if (i > 40 and i < 50) then
            set progress additional description to "Checking MAMP..."
        else if i = 50 then
            set progress additional description to mamp_exists()
        else if (i > 50 and i ≤ 60) then
            set progress additional description to "MAMP is installed..."
        else if (i > 60 and i < 70) then
            set progress additional description to "Checking Google Chrome..."
        else if i = 70 then
            set progress additional description to chrome_exists()
        else if (i > 70 and i ≤ 80) then
            set progress additional description to "Google Chrome is installed..."
        else if (i > 80 and i < 100) then
            set progress additional description to "All Dependencies Found..."
        else if i = 100 then
            set progress additional description to "Complete..."
            set progress completed steps to i
        end if

        set progress completed steps to i

        delay 0.025
    on error errTxt number errNum -- errTxt and errNum are returned from system
        display dialog errTxt & return & errNum

        exit repeat

    end try

end repeat

end dependency_check
```

It should be noted that it is calling other routines at i = 10, 30, 50, 70.

They all return text if the dependency is found.

Here is an example of one of those routines:

```
on node_exists()
    set nodeExists to do shell script "test -e /usr/local/bin/node"
    if nodeExists is not "" then -- Verifies Node.js is installed by 'test' command
        beep
        tell application "Finder" to display dialog ¬
            "Node.js is not installed, and is needed to run this program. Download Node.js and try again." with title ¬
            "Required Library Missing: Node.js!" with icon caution ¬
            buttons {"Download Node.js", "Quit Program"} ¬
            default button 2 cancel button 2
        if button returned of result is "Download Node.js" then
            open location "https://nodejs.org/en/"
            script_exit()
        end if
    else
        return "Node.js is installed..."
    end if
end node_exists
```

Thanks for any help in advance. I'm completely stuck!

Comment: just glancing at this, but have you tried `else if i >= 100 then` at end of if/then block instead of what you have?

Comment: Just tried that. Still having the same issue.